# Django send events via websocket to all clients

Tags: python, django, websocket

I want to send events (json strings) via websocket to all clients (to all who established connection via websocket). My code:

I think that asgi and routing are ok

**asgi.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'base_app.settings')
django.setup()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**routing.py**

```
from api_producer.consumers import EventWebSocket

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url('ws/start/', EventWebSocket.as_asgi()),
]
```

The problematic point:
Some function generates events and I want to send these events to the clients

```
from api_producer.consumers import EventWebSocket

def event_producer():
    my_socket = EventWebSocket()
    my_socket.receive("Some_text")
```

**consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


class EventWebSocket(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.channel_name = "CHANNEL_1"
        print("CALL_ACCEPT")
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("global", self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("global", self.channel_name)

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print("RRR_ receive ", text_data)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "global",
            {
                "type": "global.message",
                "text": text_data,
            },
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        print("CHAT_MESSAGE")
        self.send(text_data=event["text"])
    
    def global_event(self, event):
        print("GLOB_MESSAGE")
        self.send(text_data=event["text"])
```

My actions:
1 Go to websocketKing and send request **ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/start/**. Log output:

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/start/ [127.0.0.1:37194]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/start/ [127.0.0.1:37194]
CALL_ACCEPT
HTTP POST /api/start_detection/ 200 [0.57, 127.0.0.1:37238] (trigger event_producer)
```

What is the proper way to send events?

Comment: You need to call `self.accept()` in the `connect` method of your consumer to complete the handshake and complete the connection

Comment: Thank you, added. But I have error: ```  'EventWebSocket' object has no attribute 'channel_layer``` (in def receive())

Comment: You shouldn't be initialising an `EventWebSocket` object and calling `receive` on it like you are in `event_producer`. You need to get a channel layer and send a message to a group/channel that all your consumers are members of

Comment: @IainShelvington could you please elaborate? 
 How to get a channel layer?

Comment: added an answer that should hopefully demonstrate the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the events via a channel layer, [you can use channel layers outside of consumers like this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers)

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

def event_producer():
    async_to_sync(channel_layer. group_send)("global", {
        "type": "global.event",
        "text": "foo"
    })
```

And in your consumer join the global channel that the event producer sends the events on and add a method that can be triggered by the event producer. You could reuse the "chat" channel...

```
class EventWebSocket(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        ...
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("global", self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

    ...

    def global_event(self, event):
        self.send(text_data=event["text"])
```

Comment: Updated my code according to your post. But I don't receive any events  (no GLOB_MESSAGE and CHAT_MESSAGE output in logs)